# Post editor for suggestions has chopped the right side and is not aligned correctly, same for writing questions

Tags: bug, status-declined, css

**TL;dr:** Ok, there are 3 issues:

1. The right part of all fields are not aligned correctly. Rev, Title, the editor field and the preview has different widths.
2. The small yellow `?` is being chopped off.
3. The `wdm-container` div class has a `overflow: hidden` rule that is added by one of my Addons. This rule works fine in any of the SE sites but here...

I'm taking a screenshot of the current post editor. As you can see the right side is chopped off. I believe some declared css width is making a mess, but I haven't tested fully. Also,the right margin is off, I believe for the same reason.

> ```
> **Post question:**                             **Suggested edits:**
> ```
>
> [image]                                                          [image]

**This happens in Firefox (Iceweasel 25.0a2 Debian testing) with and without addons, Greasymonkey, etc.**

Chromium seems unaffected:

> ```
> **Suggested edits:**                            **Ask question:**
> ```
>
> [image]                                                        [image]

But is well known that [chrome/ium is broken by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195679/213575).

Comment: I think OS / browser version may help here... (I can't emulate this on Win7 + FireFox 23)

Comment: I can't emulate on Debian Firefox 23.0.1 either. I'm also not 100% sure what the problem is. Could you post the entire screenshot? What is the difference between whatyou see in iceweasel and chrome? Is this about the `?` being slightly sliced?

Comment: Mmhh... weird, just now it was working when I changed the theme... seems like a bug between Iceweasel, the theme and the css... Lets see if I can work around.

Comment: @terdon I think is a bug of Firefox 25, can you replicate there?

Comment: @Braiam don't really want to upgrade, this is my stable work machine.

Answer (score 2):

Declining this bug, as it involves a pre-release version of a browser.

We support **current** releases of browsers, not alpha or beta versions.